# Jquery's fadein 'slow' is too fast

Tags: jquery

i'm using the jquery fadein fadeout with the slow option, but it's still a little too fast for me.
now i've read that you can only choose between fast and slow, but is there a way to make it slower?

Comment: the millisecond variant looks good, didn't know i could do it, since i've read this in the docs: The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have two options.  The first is to use a number of milliseconds in the call:

```
$('#myItem').fadeOut(1500); // 1.5 seconds
```

The second option is to define a custom speed, or to redefine a jQuery native speed:

```
$.fx.speeds.slow = 1500; // 'slow' now means 1.5 seconds
$.fx.speeds.xslow = 3000; // 'xslow' means 3 seconds
$.fx.speeds.xfast = 100; // 'xfast' means 0.1 seconds
```

You can then call them as normal:

```
$('#myItem').fadeOut('slow');
$('#myItem').fadeOut('xslow');
$('#myItem').fadeOut('xfast');
```

This allows you to redefine speeds on an application-wide basis.

Answer (score 14):

Use a number of milliseconds rather than 'fast' or 'slow'

e.g.

```
$('#myID').fadeIn(100, function() {
  // complete
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: you can also set the fx speed globaly with $.fx.speeds._default = 250; where 250 is in milliseconds

Comment: the docs said this, so i didn't assume i could set my own millisecs: The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to 'slow'/'fast', the fadeIn function also takes a timespan in milliseconds so you can make it take however long you want:

```
$('#someId').fadeIn(3000); // 3 second fade in
```

Answer (score 3):

I really dont know how slow you want it but I recoomend something between 2500-4000

```
$('#Id').fadeIn(3500);
```

There we go